how to impelement notifications-hq ?: relation "notifications_notification" already exists
i try to implement notification-hq in django and when i send notify i got same error
relation "notifications_notification" already exists
sender=User.objects.using("default").get(username=request.user.username)
   receiver = User.objects.using("default").all()
   notify.send(sender=sender, recipient=receiver, verb='Message', description='message')

and i got this traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao/Gmao/views.py", line 41, in home
    notify.send(sender=sender, recipient=receiver, verb='Message', description='message')
.
.
.
.
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/azizi/Documents/Ufmeeg_Projects/Gmao/Gmao-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 737, in execute
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "notifications_notification" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "notifications_notification" ("level", "recipien...
                    ^
[01/Jul/2024 09:14:04] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 184506

please help me

run migrate. It does not say "already" exists, but "does not exists".
